# What does the suffix “‑erior” mean?

Tags: etymology, meaning, suffixes

The suffix *‑erior* is used in many words that seem to indicate position:

- *superior*
- *inferior*
- *anterior*
- *posterior*

However, with my Google-fu, I can’t find a real definition or etymology.

What does *‑erior* mean?  From what language does it come?

Comment: There's nothing eerier than finding that the thing you wanted to ask about doesn't even *exist*!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your Google-fu probably fails because the suffix is "-ior", not -"erior". For example, there are the words "excelsior", "senior", "junior".

The Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology says:

> *-ior* formerly also *-iour* — F. *-ieur*, † *-iour* — L. *iōrem*, nom. *-ior*, suffix of compar. of adj., as in *anterior*, *exterior*, *inferior*, *interior*, *junior*, *posterior*, *senior*, *ulterior*. In *warrior* the ending has another origin.

So, it comes from Latin via French.

Comment: However, in Latin I think it is justifiable to refer to a suffix "-erior", because that group of words (including "interior" and "exterior") are all positional, but the "-er" is etymological only for some of them. I suspect that apart from "superior", where the root is "super" (cf Greek "hyper", English "over") most of them include the I-E suffix "-tor/ter" meaning "one of two" (Lat "alter" = "one or other", "dexter" = "right hand"; Gk "heteros" = "other", "deuteros" = "second"; Russian  "vtoroi" = second, English "other", "either"). "Inferior" and "ulterior" I suspect arose by analogy.

Comment: @ColinFine, the positive _*ulter(us)_ is not attested in Latin, but it is the basis from which many derivations are formed, and it is indeed formed with the regular contrastive suffix _*-(t)ero-_, which is also the basis for the English comparative in _-er_ (without the t). The same is true of _inferus_, which also has _-er-_ in the root. I don’t think you can really posit an _-erior_ suffix in Latin—all the words that end in _-erior_ are fairly transparently a combination of _*-(t)ero-_ + _-ior_. (_Superior_ and _inferior_ perhaps less so, synchronically.)

Comment: If there is a form of the _-ter_ suffix without a 't', then presumably it underlies the Latin comparative _-ior_ as well.